# how to create a hot key for JButton which will be active everywhere, even when the jframe is not focused

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am making a simple voice recognition program for myself in java swing, and I want a hot key that I can use to access the start button (JButton startButton) actionListener. As long as the application is open, the hot key should work even if i am using a different application. I tried using mnemonics with the keys windows + a, but it only works when the startButton is focused. Can someone please help me make this hot key? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: *"I am making a simple voice recognition program .."*  You have an interesting definition of 'simple'.  What you require ('active everywhere button') is not really available without native code.

Comment: *"the hot key should work even if i am using a different application"* Not really feasible through Java alone, you'll need to look into using a native binding of some kind (JNI/JNA)

Comment: so how do you do this?

Comment: Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to notify the person of a new comment.  *"how do you do this?"*  I don't mess with native code.  But you need to know: a) it boils down to 'use some other language (not Java)' b) SO is not a 'gimme te codez' site..

Comment: Do a search for JNI/JNA solutions which provide access to the OS message loop and process key events...